# Not able to click list child element from side menu using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

It's my first week using the react library and I'm a bit confused with this piece where I have a list of items that are part of a side menu. I can assert their texts identifying them as the child of the parent List tag. But when I try to fire a click event this way it won't navigate me to the next page. It will only work if I target that list item by their text directly, not as the child of the parent list, which I'm trying to avoid because there may be other clickable elements with that same title on the page. If anyone could please point me towards what I may be lacking in understanding here please.

```
describe('App when it is rendered in a certain state:', () => {
beforeAll(() => {
    render(<Root/>);
});

it('should render the dashboard after logging in', async () => {
    
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('dashboard')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByTestId('side-menu')).toBeInTheDocument();

    const liArr = screen.queryAllByRole('listitem')
    expect(liArr[0].textContent).toBe('Dashboard')
    expect(liArr[1].textContent).toBe('Schools')
    expect(liArr[2].textContent).toBe('Teachers')

    const teachersLink = liArr[2];
    expect(teachersLink).toBeInTheDocument();
    // await fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Teachers')) // This navigates me fine
    await fireEvent.click(teachersLink);  // This does not navigate me
    expect(screen.getByText('Teachers page')).toBeInTheDocument(); 

});

});
```

This is the SideMenu component where the links come from:

```
export default function SideMenu() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root} data-testid="side-menu">
            <List>
                <ListItemLink to="/dashboard" primary="Dashboard"/>
                <ListItemLink to="/schools" primary="Schools"/>
                <ListItemLink to="/teachers" primary="Teachers"/>
            </List>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was not working because the link item was actually not clickable, not being an anchor element. Changed it to the below piece and it worked, warranting uniqueness through the role of a button.

```
async function navigateToTeachersPage() {
  await fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Teachers' }));
  expect(screen.getByTestId('teachers')).toBeInTheDocument();
}
```